# Making fcron run all jobs in a manually given time range?

Tags: cron

How do I tell fcron, to run all jobs scheduled for a time range that I’d give as a parameter.

My PC might be off in the scheduled time, e.g. because I slept at an unusual time.
And I can’t run them at boot, due to a race condition with scripts that update dynamic (e.g. weather-based) jobs, that have to be up-to-date for the other jobs to run properly.

So I would like to tell fcron something like

```
fcrondyn --run-range-manually '07:00' '13:00'
```

to avoid manually looking up all the jobs and running them myself to get back to the normal state.

Modifying the cron job file (`fcrontab -e`) is out of the question, and would not make anything more automatic anyway.

Comment: anacron exists specifically to run things on machines that are not always on  - does that work for you?  Note that if you have scripts that are dependent on each other, it makes sense to have them communicate their state to each other.

Comment: @Paul: Well, it solves one or several cases of the reason why I would want to run a range manually. Thanks for that. I’ll look into anacron.
This is just a temporary fix though, until my new OS is ready that will make anything “cron” obsolete anyway.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049460/cron-jobs-and-random-times-within-giving-hours There was a similar problem and solution offered.

Comment: @TimConnor: Than you, but I can’t find anything related to _manually_ running jobs in there. Can you point me to the specific part you mean?